# How to add Chrome New URL?

Tags: google-chrome

How to add new custom URL for my chrome (just like picture below)? I am not sure what this feature is called.

[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at Google's official documentation [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2918032?hl=en), this is a list of your most visited pages. You used to be able to customize this list via editing a file or manually pinning, but Google removed that ability. There is an extension called [Speed Dial 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-dial-2/jpfpebmajhhopeonhlcgidhclcccjcik) that allows you to create your own New Tab page that would achieve what you are looking for.